# How to I get a function to run my entire game?

Tags: c, function

I'm making a game where I want the person playing to level up if the reach a certain score. I have created a working function that will make this happen but if I want it to run I have to type 
    `functname();`
Which can get really annoying, and I may forget to put it somewhere. Is there a way where I can type 1 or 2 lines of code and the code in this function will always be running.

Comment: Hi @bobbyjoe, can you clarify your question a little more? Are you building on an existing game?

Comment: @kibibu no but I can send you the link to my game right here: https://repl.it/@bobby_joe/Ethan-C-game

Comment: So you'd like to make this function shorter and simpler? Because you can stop printing by just removing the `printf` statements

Comment: @kibibu No I am trying to get it to always be running so if score goes over a certain amount the player levels up. I am trying to do this without having to print the function whenever I want this to happen, I can just print it once.

Comment: Hi Bobbyjoe, if you're doing a game loop, the standard way is just to run the function every loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to improve this function is to take advantage of the **modulus operator** - which is just the result of a division statement.

So all your `if` statements are checking for multiples of 1000 - for one of those the remainder of `score` divided by 1000 will be zero.

In most languages I'm familiar with, modulus is done using the percent sign: `%`

So this function could be:

```
void scoretolevel(){
    /* If we're not level 10 yet, and the score is a multiple of 1000 */
    if(level < 10 && (score % 1000) == 0) {
        /* the level is the score / 1000 */
        level = (int)score / 1000;

        /* show a different message if we're level 10 */
        if(level == 10) {
            printf("Congratulations you are now at level 10, This is the max level. Well Done!");
        else {
            printf("Congratulations, you are now at level %d", level);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a bad idea at all, but the original question has `level 3` for both `2000` and `3000` (no way to know if that is a typo). It's somewhat unclear why the original was asked in terms of ranges (e.g. `>=`) rather than `==`? No telling. Still worth the UV.